# Cómo tener un spinner sin marcar un valor por defecto

Tags: java, android, spinner

Estoy iniciandome con android y me quiero plantear este ejercicio:

> Implementar un spinner con una lista de países utilizando un ArrayAdapter.
>   Muestra un Toast con la opción seleccionada y su posición.

Bien, hago todo, salvo por el hecho de que se automarca el primer item por defecto, y quisiera saber si es posible quitarlo, sin tener que añadir un item vacío.

Mi código Java es ahora

```
spiner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

String[] paises = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paises);

final ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, paises);

spiner.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
        if (pos>0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "has pulsado " + adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos) + "-" + (pos - 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Para que quede bien, si no me equivoco puedes hacer spiner.Text ="Seleccione una opcion";

Answer (score 0):

Claro que se puede, lo que tu necesitas es utilizar el método **setSelection**. Tomando en cuenta que tu listado de opciones es un array y empieza desde la posición 0.

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
spiner.setSelection(-1);
```

De una manera más detallada tu código fuente podría quedar de la siguiente manera

```
spiner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

String[] paises = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.paises);

final ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, paises);

spiner.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

spiner.setSelection(-1);

spiner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
    if (pos>0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "has pulsado " + 
        adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos) + "-" + (pos - 1), 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Elige una posición 
         valida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
}

});
```

Comment: Perfecto Oscar¡ Gracias